# Interfaces and methods with generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have two small classes, `Pet` and `Book` each with a couple of properties and a function with a method like

```
 public static List<T> GetSubSet<T>(List<T> incomingList)
        {
            var returnList = new List<T>();
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter size of random subset: ");
            int randomInt = 0;
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (size > incomingList.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Size too large, enter smaller subset: ");
                size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            while (returnList.Count < size)
            {
                randomInt = r.Next(incomingList.Count);
                if (!returnList.Contains(incomingList[randomInt]))
                {
                    returnList.Add(incomingList[randomInt]);
                }
            }

            return returnList;
        }
```

that takes a generic list of objects and returns a smaller subset.  The function works and can take either a Pet or Book object.  I would like to use the same function on a list that contains **both** Pet and Book types.  The best way that I know how to do this is with an interface (inheritance doesn't make sense here).

```
interface ISubset<T>
    {

        IEnumerable<T> GetSubset();
    }
```

When I implement the interface on my Pet class it looks like

```
  class Pet : ISubset<Pet>
```

In my Main class I have a list of Pets and Books.  I would like to add both of these two a list of `ISubset` objects so I can use the GetSubset function on both.  I can't, however, declare a list like

```
List<ISubset<T>> list = new List<ISubset<T>>();
```

I get the error `'the type or namespace T could not be found`.`
How can I declare a list of ISubset objects when the interface accepts a generic type?

Ok, I have two lists like

```
List<Pet> petList = new List<Pet>();
        petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mr.", Species = "Dog" });
        petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mrs.", Species = "Cat" });
        petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mayor", Species = "Sloth" });
        petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Junior", Species = "Rabbit" });


List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "Me", PageCount = 100, Title = "MyBook" });
        bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "You", PageCount = 200, Title = "YourBook" });
        bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "Pat", PageCount = 300, Title = "PatsBook" });
```

What should the type be if I want to add these lists together into another list?

Comment: Why not simply `List<object>`?

Comment: What type has your list of Pets and Books?

Comment: Because there will be two different types of objects: pets and books in the list.

Comment: You need to instintiate the list with the specific type (like List <Pet>

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I'm trying to make it a list like List<ISubset<T>> with T being the being a generic type of either Pet or Book, but that doesn't compile

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, a `List<object>` can store pets and books.

Comment: Maybe inheritance would works better than simple interface in your case?

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas I don't think that would work here since there's no logical connection between the two objects.

Comment: @Hogan yes: how can I create a list of both types using the generic interface I have, `ISubset`

Comment: Subset returns a List<T> don't you just need a `List<List<T>>` -- maybe you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Or if you always have two things you could make a function that works on `Tuple<List<Pet>,List<Book>>`

Comment: @Hogan I'm sure that I am :).  I don't think I'm quite grokking the details of an interface with a generic type.

Comment: ok, Why do you need an interface?  Maybe if you go back to the question and explain exactly what you are trying to do -- with some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merely use a `List<object>`, but if you want to do it the way you propose then you need to create an interface with a signature that covers both your classes

```
public interface IGen
{
    int A;
    int Method;
}
```

Then inherit/implement this interface in your classes

```
public class Pet : IGen
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    private int Method(){ ... }
}

public class Book : IGen
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    private int Method(){ ... }
}
```

Then you can pass into your `GetSubSet` like

```
GetSubSet<IGen>(List<IGen> incomingList) { ... }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`List<object>` should work fine.

The following was tested in LinqPad

```
void Main()
{
    List<Pet> petList = new List<Pet>();
            petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mr.", Species = "Dog" });
            petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mrs.", Species = "Cat" });
            petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Mayor", Species = "Sloth" });
            petList.Add(new Pet() { Name = "Junior", Species = "Rabbit" });


    List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
            bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "Me", PageCount = 100, Title = "MyBook" });
            bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "You", PageCount = 200, Title = "YourBook" });
            bookList.Add(new Book() { Author = "Pat", PageCount = 300, Title = "PatsBook" });

    List<object> both = petList.OfType<object>().Union(bookList.OfType<object>()).ToList().Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Pet
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Species { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
  public string Author { get; set; }
  public int PageCount { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why doesn't List<ISubset><T>> work?  and I like the use of LINQ like that.

Comment: This does not work. Rather write: `List<object> both = petList.Cast<object>().Union(bookList.Cast<object>()).ToList();`. Note: Any type can be assigned to `object` like this `object obj = x;`, but not collections! `SomeCollection<object> = SomeCollection<T>` does not work!

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Not sure, you mean `List<ISubset<T>>`?  Wouldn't `T` need to be of type `object` anyway?  What does ISubset define?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Thanks, I'd made that change already just before I saw your comment... tested and posted the tested code.

Comment: Okay, note that `OfType` filters, while `Cast` casts.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Yes I like oftype better because it won't throw an exception.  To each their own.  In this case there should not be any difference.

Comment: T is just a placeholder for a type that you can use when you **define** types or functions, but you need to specialize T when you **create** instances. You can't create a `List<ISubset<T>>` because when you're declaring an instance you can no longer have generic parameters like T.

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: This is not completely true. In a `class X<T>` you can create a list with `var list = new List<ISubset<T>>();` and even create new objects with `T obj = new T();` if you add `where T : new()` to the class declaration.

Comment: @olivier in that case you're not creating an instance. That will happen when you create an instance of the containing class (and specialize T). But I get your point, I've not been 100% clear.